# Why TextBox value is showing Null when i access TextBox that is inside a Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

> I'm facing a problem in my online shopping cart project ....
>   The Problem is when i get/access the Textbox that is inside a repeater control...
>   I used this below code but when i enter some value to that Textbox than it shows null value....

code behind:

```
protected void repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "addtoCartName")
        {

            foreach (RepeaterItem item in repeater1.Items)
            {
                TextBox txtName = (TextBox)item.FindControl("txtQuantity");
                if (txtName!= null)
                {

                    strText = strText + ", " + txtName.Text;
                    Response.Write("Text =" + strText);


                }
            }
       }
```

aspx:

```
<asp:Button  runat="server" ID="addtoCart" Text="Add to Cart"  CommandName="addtoCartName" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
```

[TextBox position...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIKaJ.png)

[And here the c# code...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5veI.png)

please must reply
thanks

Comment: Is txtQuantity positioned in another container? Extend the aspx info in your question.

Comment: i added an image where i write the Textbox control plz check it

Comment: @Heartlion how are you calling your data binding method

Comment: ` if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                string pid=Request.QueryString["pid"];
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from product where pid="+pid,con);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);

                repeater1.DataSource = dt;
                repeater1.DataBind();
            } `

Answer (score 1):

I think looping through repeater control is causing the issue as you can't be sure it's accessing correct row's textbox control. You need to get textbox from the row from which the event is raised:

```
protected void repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "addtoCartName")
    {
        TextBox txtName = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txtQuantity")

        if (txtName!= null)
        {
            strText = strText + ", " + txtName.Text;
            Response.Write("Text =" + strText);
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have TextBox inside ItemTemplate of ListItem not in Header/Footer etc. so you need to check Item Type of the Repeater Item.
Try this :

```
 foreach (RepeaterItem item in repeater1.Items)
   {             
  if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
     {
          TextBox txtName = (TextBox)item.FindControl("txtQuantity");
          if (txtName!= null)
           {
             strText = strText + ", " + txtName.Text;
             Response.Write("Text =" + strText);
           }
      }
   }
```

Comment: thnx for answering but it still returning null value
e.g:     Text=

Comment: Did it enter to the first if condition??

Comment: yes it enters to the first if condition as well as enter into the another if condition and in its body either i enter some value into the textbox or not...

is there any alternative way??

Comment: -i mean i'm developing online shopping cart
-there is an index page where all the products shows
-when i click any product then it shows in another page called ProductDetail.aspx
-so here in ProductDetail.aspx i'm using repeater control for binding database values..
-i know there is no use of repeater because i'm just retreiving the product once...
-is there any alternative way ?? where i can use all the controls in ProductDetail page easily

Comment: I am confuse about your error? If you want to add one item into add to cart as you said then why you are looping through all your row on  repeater? you can get the row Id from which event got fired. which data  is your strText variable handling?

Comment: Yes you could create one simple table well arrange all controls as you want to view ProjectDetail Page then on code behind set the value of all the control you want. Could you please share a screen shot where your Add to cart and detail are present?